# WCF hosted on IIS - How to get CPU and Memory Utilization for Individual services under same application pool

Tags: wcf, iis, monitoring

WCF hosted on IIS  - How to get CPU and Memory Utilization for Individual W3WP services under same application pool

Process ID for each  w3wp.exe for each instance is changing.

Comment: There are ways to associated process IDs with application pools, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2009/10/22/which-w3wp-exe-pid-corresponds-to-which-application-pool/ But there is no direct way to monitor such at pool level. So you have to roll out your own scripts/tools.

Comment: Is there any way to collect App Pool utilization from IIS server  worker process feature where it show the CPU and Memory utilization ?